# Bonobo Git Server 5.2.0 on Win 2012 + IIS8.0

Tags: git, iis-8, windows-server-2012, bonobo

I have a problem with installing Git serve on my Windows Server 2012 Standart x64...
I have run all instructions mmentiont in `https://bonobogitserver.com/install/`
But I can't acces webpages, only what I see is directory listing on my webbrowser...
[image]

So what I am wrong, and how to fix it?

P.S I'm new into Server installation, so maybe missed some libraries in installation steps

Comment: Does anybody know about my question?

Comment: There are a million reasons why an ASP.NET application won't run, but for a starting point I wouldn't recommend using "5.2" as the name of the application - dots in URLs can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed [ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4)?
This includes the installation of MS SQL Server 2008 Express.
And after that, the server roles will be possible to include support ASP.NET 4.5 features in IIS server.